# How to open templates using vim?

Tags: vim, templates

Using the GUI, when I right-click, there is an option to open a new document that can be empty or **a template**. This opens (by default) in [gedit](https://projects.gnome.org/gedit/).

How do I open these templates using [vim](http://www.vim.org/%E2%80%8E)(without modifying the original ones, so that I can use as they are later too)? By this I mean I don't want to open the templates going to `~/Templates`.

[image: opening templates from GUI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [vim-template](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2834) plugin. Once downloaded, you can find all the necessary documentation in `doc/template.txt`.